# Equivalence of two methods for generating random numbers that sum to 1

Tags: probability

I want a vector $\vec{v}$ of $N$ non-negative random numbers that sum to 1.

Let $X(a)$ be the (continuous) uniform distribution over interval $[0, a]$.

Let $S(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} v_{i}$ be the partial sum of the elements of $\vec{v}$

**Method 1**

- Generate: For each $k$, set $v_k$ to a random number from $X(1)$.
- Normalize: Divide $\vec{v}$ by sum of all elements of $\vec{v}$.

**Method 2**

Generate the elements of $\vec{v}$ one after another with the following steps.

1. Generate 1st element: set $v_1$ to a random number from $X(1)$.
2. Generate 2nd element: set $v_2$ to a random number from $X(1 - v_{1})$

   ...
3. Generate the $k^{th}$ element: set $v_k$ to a random number from $X(1 - S(k-1))$.

   ...
4. Calculate the last element: set $v_N$ to $1 - S(N - 1)$.

**Question**

Are the two methods equivalent?

Do the two methods generate $\vec{v}$ with the same $N$ dimensional probability density?

Thank you.

Comment: If I don't like some elements, method 2 allows me to regenerate later elements while keeping earlier elements fixed. Method 1 would require me to regenerate all the elements, which would take more time. I am quite sure that method 1 is correct because many computer programs use method 1.

Comment: Found a problem with method 1. It is not uniform sampling over the standard simplex. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/uniform-sampling-from-a-simplex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are certainly not equivalent. It is easy to see that in the first method, $\mathbb{E}[v_n]=\frac 1n$, while in the second method, $\mathbb{E}[v_k]=\frac 1{2^k}$ (you can prove this with induction and linearity of expectation), and so $\mathbb{E}[v_n]=\frac 1{2^n}$.

---

In response to a comment on another answer, scrambling the elements of the array also does not make the methods equivalent.

With method 2, there is a $\frac 13$ probability that there exists an element with value greater than $\frac 23$ (this is the element that was chosen first).

With method 1, there is only a small probability that some element has value greater than $\frac 23$. To show this, let the vector before normalization be $u$, so that $v=\frac u{\sum u}$. Let us consider the case where element $n$ has value greater than $\frac 23$. Clearly this happens only if $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}u_i \leq \frac {u_n}2 \leq \frac 12$. But if $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}u_i \leq \frac 12$, then $u_i \leq \frac 12 \forall i \in [1\dots n-1]$, and clearly this only happens with probability $\frac 1{2^{n-1}} \leq \frac 13$. (Union bounding only changes this to $\frac n{2^{n-1}}$, which is $\leq \frac 13.$)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is that these do not give equivalent distributions if the order of your vector matters (i.e. the entries are considered in-exchangeable).

To see this, we note that under Method 1, any of the $N$ samples is equally likely to be the biggest sample. In particular this means for $2 \leq n \leq N$:

$$ \mathbf P[ v_1 \geq v_n] = \frac12.$$

Now considering Method 2, there is a natural order to the problem that implies that on average earlier samples $v_k$ will be larger than later ones.

Consider the case $N = 3$, and note that
$$v_3 = 1 - v_1 - v_2$$

Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf P[v_1 \geq v_3] &= \mathbf P[v_2 \geq 1-2v_1] \\
& =\int_{0}^1 \mathbf P[v_2 \geq 1 - 2v_1 | v_1 = s] \mathbf P[v_1 = s] ds \\
& = \int_{0}^1 \mathbf P[v_2 \geq 1 - 2s |v_1=s] ds \\
& = \int_{0}^1 \left\{ 1 - \mathbf P[v_2 \leq 1 - 2s |v_1=s]\right\} ds \\
& = \int_{0}^1 \left\{1 - P(v_2 \leq 1 - 2s|v_2 \sim\text{Unif}[0,1-s]) \right\}ds\\
& = 1 - \int_0^1 \frac{1-2s}{1-s}\mathbf 1\left(0 \leq 1-2s \leq 1-s\right)ds
\\
& = 1 - \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1-2s}{1-s}ds \\
& = \log(2) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
In particular we have $P[v_1 \geq v_3] > \frac12$, so the two distributions do not agree.

Comment: This seems a little overkill, but good answer otherwise.

Comment: Does that mean if I use method 2 and then scramble the elements in $\vec{v}$, that will be equivalent to method 1? By scramble, I mean randomly choose 2 elements and swap their values, and repeat that for many times.

Comment: So, I'd need to think somewhat further on that, but intuitively I think this seems reasonable. You might find it helpful to read up on order statistics for the uniform distribution.

Comment: @Rzu no. This is a direct consequence of my answer.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy but if I scramble the ordering of elements, the expectation of all scrambled elements would be the same.

Comment: With a bit more thought, I agree with @DreamConspiracy that these still would not be equivalent. My intuition is as follows: on average in method 1 you'll draw N variables which are all roughly the same size and equal to $1/2$, so your partition of $[0,1]$ will be into roughly equal pieces. In method 2, you always have this `telescoping' property where the later samples are constrained to be very small. So even after re-ordering these partitions will look very different: one will have partition pieces of successively smaller sizes, whilst the other will be largely uniformly sized pieces.

Comment: @Rzo I have added the analysis to my answer.

Comment: @owen88 yes, this is exactly my intuition. I formalized this in the edit to my answer.